# How to change color of filename when fileupload object has a file browsed

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a FileUpload control as:

```
<asp:FileUpload CssClass="FU" ID="FileToUpload" runat="server" />
```

CssClass FU is defined as:

```
.FU {
position:fixed;
margin-top:150px;
margin-left:437px;
height:25px;
color:#F3514C;
}
```

When page loads in Google Chrome, FileUpload object status is written as "No File Chosen" infront of FileUpload object. Its color is `color:#F3514C` as defined in CssClass FU. 
What I want to do is, when a user browses a file using FileUpload Browse button and adds a file in FileUpload object and file name is shown in FileUpload status text, I want its text color to change to green so that a user comes to know that FileUpload object has successfully read the path of browsed file.

Your answer is much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. Hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `JQuery` as shown below:

```
<asp:FileUpload CssClass="FU" ID="FileToUpload" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#' + '<%=FileToUpload.ClientID %>').change(function() {
        var fileName = $(this).val();

        if (fileName != '') {
            $(this).css('color', 'green');
        } else {
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
</script>
```